# Hide button after page is saved as html

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the bottom of html page, there's a **button** with onClick function.

As the page has only internal css, when users save the page (Right click > Save As) as html file, the page is saved without additional folders (just html) but the button is visible at the bottom.

How to hide the button when people save html page. After saving, when they open it on their computer, the button should be hidden because it doesn't work without scripts so it has no purpose to stay there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on the comment string in Diodeus's answer, you could use Javascript to generate the button. Provided the script file is linked and not hosted, it won't be accessible when the user saves the page, and therefore the button would never be generated. Something like this:

Header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Where `script.js` is the Javascript to generate your button. that script should include something like:

```
window.onload = button; 

function button() { 
  //generate button here 
}
```

Since `script.js` doesn't exist on the user's local machine, it will never run and the button will not exist. It does however exist on your hosted server and so any user visiting your site will see the button.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript has no event for this type of action. You cannot determine when a user saves a page. It is part of the browser itself, not part of the page.

Comment: What about using `oncontextmenu` to remove the button from the DOM? Not a perfect solution, but it would remove the button when a user right-clicks...

Comment: Maybe, but the user can still save from the application menu, which cannot be captured.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought too... There is no real fool-proof way, other than maybe generating the button server-side, but that seems like over-kill.

Comment: You could inject the button into the DOM after page load using JavaScript.

Comment: Injecting it into the DOM as @Diodeus says would be the most effective way of accomplishing this behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, as long as the script is not a 'hosted' source, then the script wouldn't download with the rest of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button hidden by default (using CSS: `display:none;`), and then unhide it with Javascript when the page loads. You can do this by adding (or removing) a CSS class, or by updating the button's `style` attribute directly.

Comment: Although, if I may interject my personal opinion: Don't try to outsmart the user, because 9 out of 10 times you will only end up making the experience more frustrating. Assuming this a typical web page (and not a feature of some weird software that cranks out reports in HTML format, or something), I would say it's safe to assume the user knows what they are doing. Just let them do it.

Comment: You really think that people who are saving a page as html and then expecting it to work the same know what they're doing?

Comment: How often do people save webpages as HTML? I don't think people do that very often; that's kind of my point. Someone who's going out of their way to download the HTML source of the page probably has a good reason for doing so, and likely understands the ramifications of opening the page "offline" (and if they don't, this will be a good learning experience for them).

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the current url with `document.URL` and if it is equal to `C:\` or `http://localhost` than do `$('button').remove();`